# Capybara-webkit, javascript integration test not working

Tags: rspec, capybara, capybara-webkit

Hi I am having issues when running my specs, it seems that I cannot log in when I turn on javascript for my tests.

```
describe "logging in" do 
  let!(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

  before do
     visit new_user_session_path
     fill_in "Email", with: user.email
     fill_in "Password", with: user.password
     click_link "Sign in"
  end

  it "should do something" do
    page.should have_css('.flash', text: "You have successfully signed in") 
  end
end
```

What is weird is that this works perfectly fine. What is weird is that when I try to turn on js by changing the first line to: `describe "loggin in", js: true do`, the test fails and says invalid email password combination in the flash notice.

I am using `Rails 3.2.6`, `rspec-rails (2.11.0)`, and `capybara-webkit (0.12.1)`. My spec helper has the line `Capybara.javascript_driver = :webkit`.

I am not sure what exactly is going on, I have used pry to check that the user is created (it is) although I am not positive how to check that the fields are being filled in correctly. I believe that they are being filled in correctly because it works when javascript is turned off.

Note, I know you don't need javascript for this test but I didn't feel like posting the actual spec.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out you need `config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true` in your `#config/environments/test.rb`